# Please reopen "Did Maeve choose to go and save her child of her own free will?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Can we reopen the following question?

> [Did Maeve choose to go and save her child of her own free will?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146598/did-maeve-choose-to-go-an-save-her-child-of-her-own-free-will)

The question is answerable with only the information provided in the episode in question. I don't think it is opinion based. In S2 they may overturn what we were shown in S1, but until then we should have enough information to come to a conclusion.

The fact that it asks about "free will" may be a little too broad and may need some editing to keep it constrained to topics that were actually defined in the story.

Comment: The 'support' tag is used when you need support with a site feature, not when you're trying to canvass for support from the community.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. I had no idea and really didn't want to tag it at all. Clearly my knowledge of site features is also lacking.

Comment: No worries. The whole point of the rep system is that as you gain more rep, you get more responsibility but also a greater duty to share knowledge.

Comment: OP here - The question has been edited since it was closed and hopefully that will bring it more in line with the scope of the site. You can vote to reopen it now. As for your point on free will being too broad I totally disagree - this is a central theme of both the series, this specific episode and Maeve in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is once again open. I made an edit to request info from the first season only, which prevents it from falling foul of the "Future Works" policy. Based on how rapidly it reopened, the community clearly feel that this was a positive edit.

Comment: Either that, or people are eager to get a review queue badge for VTRO queue :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Some people choose to see the ugliness in this world, the disarray. I choose to see the beauty. To believe there is an order to our days.

Comment: Some men just want to watch the world burn.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Some want the world to burn without any need to assume gender. :-)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - it was an exact quote from the Nolan Batman film

Comment: @Valorum there's a deeper level to this meta. And I intend to find it.

Comment: @Ber - There is actually a secret mod-only chatroom where the mods gather to make snarky comments about users. Does that count as a "deeper level"?

Comment: @Valorum everything is secretly engineered by [Jeff Atwood](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood).

Comment: @Valorum Shhh hhhh hhhh hhhh! At least they do. Not know the number. I am dropping no. Hints in this comment.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I am not a number! I am a free mod!

Comment: @Randal'Thor You are a number. Not a free mod. Your case sounds like. A reverse "Atlantis Complex".